# Python OpenCV pure white background

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have a DIY home photo studio to take photos. I want them to be on pure white background (#FFFFFF) with minimum user interaction

This is original picture i have (no any processing, just raw JPG from camera)
[image: original image]

I implement simple python program with opencv and Tkinter for UI

**1) Get rect with object (ROI)**

I decide to select ROI with UI, maybe later i will write code to automatically recognize object on the photo.

[image: select ROI]

**2) With cv2.grabCut function i try to cut background from this rect**

[image: grab cut with rect]

```
cv2.grabCut(image, self.mask, rect, bgdmodel, fgdmodel, 5, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
```

**3) If necessary i create custom mask for grabcut which can provide more accuracy object extraction**

[image: grab cut with mask]

```
cv2.grabCut(image, self.mask, rect, bgdmodel, fgdmodel, 5, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)
```

**4) After this step i can create mask where my object is located. I also resize mask by 30px**

```
mask = cv2.resize(mask, ( crop_img.shape[1] + 30,  crop_img.shape[0] + 30))
mask = mask[30 : crop_img.shape[0], 30 : crop_img.shape[1]]
```

so this mask have more width and height

[image: object mask]

**5) I use this mask for seamlessClone method**

```
src_bg = 255 * np.ones(self.src.shape, self.src.dtype)

width, height, channels = src_bg.shape
center = (int(height / 2), int((width / 2)))
output = cv2.seamlessClone(crop_img, src_bg, mask, center, cv2.MIXED_CLONE)
```

And get such result:
[image: output]

Looks good except some artifacts on the right side of object. It seems like my mask isnt fit good. This is not a real problem. Real problem is: seamlessClone give me not really white background. Take a look at levels:

[image: levels]

Some strange gradients and background isn't really white on bottom right corner. I try with many images and there is often such things.

My question is: what is a proper way to do what i want? Is my approach can used for this task and how to make really white (#FFFFFF) background without such gradients. Thanks

Comment: maybe use more lamps when you take photo.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are willing to consider another tool, but if you are on Linux, **ImageMagick** is probably installed and is able to do this very easily without any coding. It is also available for OS X and Windows.

So, if we start with this image:

[image]

and let's assume that the coordinates for the red lines correspond to an image that is 550px wide by 480px tall and offset 250,200 from the top-left of the picture. Then, just at the command-line in Terminal, you can run:

```
convert photo.jpg -crop 550x480+250+200 \
   -fuzz 25% -fill white -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' -trim result.jpg
```

giving you this:

[image]

That command-line means... *"Open `photo.jpg` and crop out the red part. Allow 25% variation in colour from the pixel at top-left corner and flood-fill the image with pure white. Trim it. Save as `result.jpg`"*

You can set the *fuzz* percentage higher for a harder edge.

Comment: ImageMagick add weird edges

Answer (score 1):

If you [bump up the contrast](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html) before segmenting for your mask you might be able to get rid of the shadow without extra lights or the manual initialization.

For such a clean background you could try another segmentation like [Watershed](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html). It also uses markers but it's a little faster.

You can get inner markers from [distance transforms](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#distancetransform) + threshold, outer markers from a threshold + [dilation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#dilation) and if you want them you can get the lines from the edge with [Hough Transforms](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) or [active contours](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_active_contours.html).

I think your `seamlessClone` is causing the gradient. The 'seamless' part is due to blending. Just multiply your black mask by your image to remove the background then add the result to a white image.